# letsencrypt nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I am using centos6 linux vps and i have installed nginx on my server. I have installed letsencrypt SSL certificate . But the thing is that when i go to my website www.mywebsite.com ,it shows SECURE but when i go to www.mywebsite.com/otherpages ,it shows Insecure and letsencrypt certificate invalid.

The configuration of "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"

```
server {
listen      80  default_server;
#  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  _;
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location / {
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
}
```

the configuration of /etc/nginx/sites-available/quiznou.com.conf

```
   server {
    listen     80    ;
    server_name quiznou.com www.quiznou.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
   server{
  listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name quiznou.com www.quiznou.com;
  ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/quiznou.com/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/quiznou.com/privkey.pem;
 ssl_session_timeout 5m;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

 location / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
 location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root       /var/www/quiznou.com;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this my own configuration files of NGINX as a revers_proxy: but I'm using configuration to proxy some docker. I modified directly the `/etc/nginx/default.conf` ,to proxy an `apache web page` I've created a VHost in `nginx`.

If it could help you.

```
server {
listen       80;
listen  443 ssl;
server_name  some.name.com;
server_tokens off;

## Certificates
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.name.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.name.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.name.com/chain.pem;
if ($scheme = http){

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
location / {
proxy_pass http://IP_du_serveur:port;
}

## Protocol
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

## Diffie-Hellman
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

## Ciphers
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+AES;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# OCSP Stapling
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

## TLS parameters
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

## HSTS
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubdomains;   preload";
}
```